# Fragment and activity communication

Tags: android

Why is it better to use `interface` when passing data from a fragment to the activity over calling a method in the activity using `getActivity()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interface is better to avoid the strong coupling between the **fragment** and a specific type of **Activity**.

Also it's useful in case I want to pass data between **two fragments** instead passing between a fragment and an Activity.

Answer (score 0):

"To increase reuse of fragments, they should not directly communicate with each other. Every communication of the fragments should be done via the host activity.

For this purpose a fragment should define an interface as an inner type and require that the activity, which uses it, must implement this interface. This way you avoid that the fragment has any knowledge about the activity which uses it."

I recommend you to read the full fragments-tutorial:
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html